# Is a subspace created by the vectors.....

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the subspace $$A= \Bigg\lbrace \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\0 \end{bmatrix}:\quad x_1 , x_2\in \mathbb R \Bigg\rbrace$$

Spanned by

$$a=  \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$  and

$$b=  \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}$$

I tried showing linear independence and then showed that  (x1, x2, 0) is a subspace.

Is the idea of solving this problem correct?

Comment: The right word is not created, it is spanned. However, if you want to show that $a,b$  span the subspace given above, you need to show it is a subspace, show that $a,b$ belong to that space, then show that $\{a,b\}$ is a linearly independent set which spans it. Alternately, you can show that $a,b$ are linearly independent and then find the dimension of the space above to conclude.

Comment: Ok I translated it from another language, and it is called created here.  How to I show that a,b are elements of( x1, x2 0) just by stating that the numbers 1,2,0 of a and be are on the real number line

Comment: Yes, that is correct : just matching $a,b$ with the description suffices to show that $a,b$ are elements of the subspace. Next, you have to show that $a.b$ are linearly independent. Can you do this?

Comment: I guess, I showed that only if two scalars in a linear combination produce the zero vector if the two scalars are 0

Comment: If you have showed it, then very good. It is what you are supposed to show. If you have any doubts in your working, then post it and we can look at it. Otherwise, your next step is to show that $a,b$ span the given space. Can you write every element of the space as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Ok I thought I showed that by showing linear independence proofed that. I’m so thankfull for your help! How do I do that?

Comment: At this stage, I think I must answer the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See, to show that some set "creates" , or "is a basis for" a subspace, you have to do the following :

- Show that the set is a subset of the subspace.
- Show that the set is linearly independent.
- You have two options now : either show that this set spans the subspace, or demonstrate another basis of the subspace, of the same size. Since two bases have the same size, you are done i.e. the given set is also a basis.

Now, to show that $a,b$ spans the space, just note that $(x_1,x_2,0) = x_1(1,2,0) + (x_2 - 2x_1)(0,1,0)$. So $a,b$ span the given space.

Or, just see that $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ span the given space : they are linearly independent and clearly a spanning set also. Now, two bases have the same size, and therefore $a,b$, having size two is also a basis.

Comment: Sorry that I have so many questions why (1,2,0) and (0,1,0). The other way is seeing that (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) is a basis, but how does this proof that a,b span the subspace. Bc they are linearely Independent? We have never had vectorspaces in class or linear independence but are supposed to solve this problems....

Comment: I am using $a = (1,2,0)$ and $b = (0,1,0)$. Horizontal or vertical representation makes almost no difference. Also, you may not have learnt the second point yet. Actually, to show that $a,b$ is a basis, one does not always need to show that it spans, and is linearly independent. Finding an alternate basis of the same size, lets you skip any one of these steps. In our case, we skipped showing that $a,b$ spans the space, and showed only linear independence. If you do not know this fact, then take it as truth for now : you will learn it soon.

Comment: Also, having questions is no problem. I will try to answer as many as I can : every customer must leave satisfied.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is so helpful

Comment: You are welcome!  If you like, you may accept the answer or wait for another one.